# What's the difference between "entschließen" and "beschließen"?

Tags: word-usage, difference, word-choice

Ich habe gerade in Leo gesehen, dass beide Wörter "to decide something" bedeuten.

Sagt man "Ich habe mich etwas anderes entschließen" oder "Ich habe mich etwas anderes beschließen"?

Und wo sollte man anstatt **entschließen** oder **beschließen** besser **entscheiden** benutzen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's **sich entschließen**, reflexive. Someone decides on doing something himself. Sometimes this can be subtle.

> Der Trainer entschloss sich, die Herausforderung anzunehmen.

*The coach decided to accept the challenge.*

> Die Mannschaft entschloss sich zur Aufgabe.

*The team decided on resigning.*

---

**Beschließen** can mean both. Either the subject decides on doing something itself or decides the object has to do something.

> Der Trainer beschloss, auf die gegnerische Mannschaft zu wetten.

The coach decided to place a bet on the opponent team.

> Die Mannschaft beschloss, den Trainer rauszuwerfen.

The team decided on firing the coach.

> Die Mannschaft beschloss, dass der Manager den Trainer rauszuwerfen hätte.

The team decided the manager had to fire the coach.

Comment: das bedeutet sich entschließen und sich entschieden sind gleich oder ?

Comment: They are similar. *Sich entscheiden* means there had been options to consider. In contrary you can *dich entschließen* to do something without considering other options. Focus is on the future, not the past.